# Matlab GUI dynamic discrete status tracker

Tags: matlab, user-interface, progress-bar

In Matlab GUI, I want to dynamically display a sequence of equally spaced boxes (contained within a panel) and to dynamically highlight a particular one. A sort of status tracker (my apologies, I don't know the technical term for this). Obviously the sizing and spacing should be relative to the containing panel. This GUI tracker would be embedded within a containing parent figure. Btw, they don't have to be squares. Radio buttons or just plain old push buttons would work fine. Is this possible ? If so, would it also be possible to obtain a click index on any of these boxes ? I understand that this may be asking too much from Matlab GUI. Thanks in advance.

[image: Progress Tracker]

EDIT1: This is what I have so far:

```
pnl = handles.trackerPanel;
pnlPose = get(pnl, 'Position');
pnlX = pnlPose(1); 
pnlY = pnlPose(2); 
pnlW = pnlPose(3); 
pnlH = pnlPose(4);

panelSidePad = 0.01*pnlW;
% Continuous box space
boxcontW = (pnlW - 2*panelSidePad)/N;

% Visible box: part of the continuous box space
boxW = boxcontW*0.9;
% Same thing on height
panelTopPad = pnlH*0.01;
boxH = pnlH - 2*panelTopPad;

% Indeces along the X-dimension
boxXIdc = pnlX+panelSidePad:boxcontW:pnlX+panelSidePad + boxcontW*(N-1);
boxYIdc = pnlY + panelSidePad;
trackerObjects = [];
for ii = 1:length(boxXIdc)
    objpos = [boxXIdc(ii), boxYIdc, boxW, boxH]; 
    tObj =  uicontrol('Parent', pnl,'Style','frame',...
                    'String','', 'Tag', sprintf('t_%d', ii), ...
                    'BackgroundColor', 'red',...
                    'Units','normalized','Position',objpos);
     % Register callback function. Use the same function to catch all click
     % events.
     set(tObj, 'Callback', @tracker_Callback);
     trackerObjects = [trackerObjects; tObj];
     % For a dramatic loading effect.
    drawnow();
end

if(length(boxXIdc) ~= N)
   warning('Not all trackers were displayed'); 
end
handles.trackerObjects = trackerObjects;
```

But the problem is that frames/text etc. objects do not respond to click events. I have to add buttons for that. Buttons on the other side have thick edges and when there are too many objects, the color disappears. So, does anyone know if 1) add working callbacks to frames/text or 2) make buttons appear without the "popping" edges and make them look flat and boxy. I don't see any such properties in the property inspector for any of the button objects.

EDIT 2: To obtain clicks on the frame, instead of using 'Callback', use 'ButtonDownFcn' as the click-callback function property, as in the following:

```
set(tObj, 'ButtonDownFcn', @tracker_Callback);
```

The callback now will be invoked on mouse clicks.

Comment: It is perfectly possible and there are several ways to achieve this, but it is a significant job. You should at least try to begin it yourself. Proceed step by step. Find a way to create a basic shape/object, stick it in a loop to repeat as needed (and keep the indexes of course), don't forget to parent them to a panel container (and I advise to use `'units','normalised'` inside this container). Once at this point highlighting one and blanking the other will be easier, then last add the click index. If you get stuck at one of these stage, ask again (showing your work) and you'll get help.

Comment: +Hoki I was able to try out several objects, but only buttons seem to respond to click events. Please see the code above, which is what I have so far. I can't seem to find a way to make button objects look flat and boxy. Radio buttons are just too large. Any suggestions ? Are there any simple (appearing) objects which respond to click events ?